# Storing changes on MySQL Database properly

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I've currently got three tables to track changes on specific entries but it seems like I am ending up with a ton of entries and I am not sure if that is the best possible way.

My first table holds the basic information and the second and third one the extra entries I grab every 8 hours.

`ID | creation_date | removal_date | article_url | status` which are basically the most stable entries. Status and removal_date are the only ones that will change in case we disable/remove an entry.

Example:

```
ID |  creation_date   |   removal_date   | article_url | status
---|------------------|------------------|-------------|-------
 1 | 10/01/2020 20:00 |       NULL       | http://xxx  |   1
 2 | 23/01/2020 10:00 | 27/01/2020 13:00 | http://xxx2 |   2
 3 | 10/02/2020 15:00 |       NULL       | http://xxx3 |   1

Status 1 = Active
Status 2 = Inactive
```

The second table holds everything else:
`ID | main_id | last_update | title | description | views | rating | comments`

The second table creates a new entry every 8 hours as long as something changes. Then based on the entries added here, I show average views/rating/comments changes on a daily/weekly/monthly basis.

Example:

```
ID | main_id |    last_update   |      title     |    description     | views | rating | comments
---|---------|------------------|----------------|--------------------|-------|--------|---------
 1 |    1    | 10/01/2020 20:00 | First Article  | Description..      |   1   | 1 | 0
 2 |    2    | 23/01/2020 10:00 | Second Article | Desc..             |   1   | 1 | 0
 3 |    1    | 11/01/2020 20:00 | First Article  | Description update |   15  | 3 | 2
 4 |    1    | 12/01/2020 20:00 | 1st Article    | Description update |   30  | 5 | 4
 5 |    3    | 10/02/2020 15:00 | 3rd Article    | Descript!          |   3   | 1 | 1
```

The third table holds the tags:
`ID | main_id | tag_id | date_added | date_removed`

I thought instead of having a status to add an empty date_removed so in case the tags get updated/removed/etc update that part. The tags are saved in a separate table and just grab the id and store the connection between the two here.

Example:

```
ID | main_id | tag_id |    date_added    |   date_removed
---|---------|--------|------------------|------------------
 1 |    1    |    2   | 10/01/2020 20:00 |      NULL
 2 |    1    |    3   | 15/01/2020 16:30 | 17/01/2020 13:00
 3 |    2    |    3   | 23/01/2020 10:00 |      NULL
 4 |    3    |    5   | 10/02/2020 15:00 |      NULL
 5 |    1    |    5   | 11/02/2020 17:00 |      NULL
```

I'd just like to know if there is a better / more proper way to store the above data.

Comment: Please be more concise and clear, it's very difficult to understand what kind of data are you dealing with, hence is difficult to assess how to model data.

Comment: @digitai Is it better now that I added the example tables?

Comment: Is `date_added` the same value as `creation_date`?  What about `removal_date` and `date_removed`?  Phrased another way, how many _distinct_ dates are there for each article, including any that are `NULL`?

Comment: I got lost in the description.  Can there be multiple rows for any article in any of those tables?

Answer (score 0):

Yepp,  @Maria,  is clearer.
Assuming that you are dealing with blog entries,  you may have a data model like this.

```
Table 1.  articles. // where every article is created.

article_id | article_creation_date | article_title | article_url | article_creator_id | article_description          |
-----------|-----------------------|---------------|-------------|--------------------|------------------------------|
1          | 2020/03-31 10:36:05   | "The Dilemma" | /articles/1 | 23                 | Explains the relations....|
```

Table 2. article_status // stores changes of state to each article.

```
article_status | article_id | status | date_of_change     |
---------------|------------|--------|--------------------|
1              |  1         | 7      | 15/04/2020 09:30:00|
```

Table 3.  article_tags. // every article and it's tags

```
article_tag | article_id | tag_id | date_added         |
------------|------------|--------|--------------------|
1           |  1         | 24     | 15/04/2020 09:30:00|
```

Table 4.  article views // stores the summarized amount of views to each article,  for a period, say day, week, 8 hours,...

```
article_v_id | article_id | views_summarized | time_lapse     | time_lapse_value | date_summarization |
-------------|------------|------------------|----------------|-------------------|-------------------|
1           |  1          | 1578             |  Day           | 10/04/2020        | 12/04/2020 13:27:04  |
```

Table 5.  article_updates // stores changes/updates made to each article.

```
article_update_id | article_id | type_of_update | update_detail | update_author | date_of_update         |
------------------|------------|--------------------------------|---------------|------------------------| 
1                 |  1         | Title          |               |    John Doe   | 19/04/2020 15:27:24    |
```

And the contentn of the update is stored directly on articles table,  say change of title. NO need to store all modified titles,  content.  Just the event and who made the change.

Comment: How do you also track the changes on title and/or description on the above scenario? I mean how can you see the previous entries etc? Thanks!

Comment: @Maria I'm sure you and anyone who reads this answer,  finds it extremely accurate and useful.  So please, in order to motivate pair programmers to help you,  be kind and award the answer,  this way,  the community is incentivized to collaborate with generosity.